# Riak Map/Reduce enableForSearch() error

Tags: riak, riak-search

I'm trying to use the Riak Java Client in an application, however I'm facing some errors. What I need is to perform a Riak Search query as input for a Map/Reduce. According to the [official tutorial](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client) the search property must be enabled in the Bucket. I'm doing so, in the following code:

```
IRiakClient riakClient =  RiakFactory.httpClient(HTTP_CLIENT);
Bucket bucket = (Bucket) riakClient.createBucket("test-bucket").enableForSearch().execute();
```

When I do this, the store operation, in the Bucket, doesn't work anymore. And the following error appears:

```
com.basho.riak.client.RiakRetryFailedException: java.io.IOException: 500 Error:
{precommit_fail,{hook_crashed,{riak_search_kv_hook,precommit,error,badarg}}}
```

I've already googled the problem, but it wasn't much help!

Comment: This looks like it should be asked on Riak's mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have search enabled in your app.config? Find this section

```
%% Riak Search Config
 {riak_search, [
            %% To enable Search functionality set this 'true'.
            {enabled, false}
           ]},
```

and set enabled to true.